# Removing last element from LinkedList in O(1) without iterators(java)

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to implement my own LinkedList and now my problem is removing.
I need to remove at least last element in O(1), but i can't do that. 
In every case that i looked, people are making a simple loop from head to (last - 1) element, removing tail in this way. But it has O(n) complexity.
Also i've found that LinkedList from java.util. is using iterators.
So my question is - can i remove last element without using iterators or i need to implement iterators class too?
that's my popBack() method code:

```
private void popBack(){
    if(!isEmpty()) {
        --size;
        T temp = tail.info;

        //tail.next = null;
        //tail.prev.getNext();
        tail = tail.prev;
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("OH SHI-, List is empty");
    }
}
```

(here i've changed my tail, but i haven't connected previous element with that tail, so previous element still reffers to an old element)

Comment: A linked list starts at the head. You will have to follow the chain of links to reach the last link.

Comment: Unless you have a direct reference to the last element in the list, you can't do it in O(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your list is a doubly linked list, and you do have a reference to the last element (`tail` in your code), which means you can remove the last element in `O(1)` time.

Your attempt is almost correct. In addition to changing the `tail` reference to refer to `tail.prev`, you have to set the `next` reference of the new tail to `null`.

No other nodes of the list should be affected.

```
private void popBack(){
    if(!isEmpty()) {
        --size;
        T temp = tail.info;
        tail = tail.prev;
        tail.next = null;
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

You may have to add another check for the case that the removed element was the only element (in which case `tail.prev` is probably null), and after the removal the list is empty.

Comment: ok, sure i've tried that, but when i do that i get NullPointerException

Comment: @Juicer did you remove the only element, or does your list contain more than one element? You should check that `tail != null` before trying to set `tail.next` to null (in case you removed the only element).

Comment: @Juicer - Eran's answer looks correct to me.  Please provide an MCVE that shows exactly what you are doing to get that `NullPointerException`.

Comment: yes, i assumed this answer is right. Error in my code was is other block of code as i found later.